# Pig Python UDF and lxml

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-pig, lxml

I have a Python UDF that uses lxml. My Pig job that uses the UDF fails:

```
File "PigParse.py", line 10, in ParseToPig ImportError: No module named lxml
```

The Python script works fine as a stand alone program, its line 10 is:

```
from lxml import etree
```

Do I need to distribute lxml to the hadoop cluster somehow, and if so, how and which version should I use?

I have seen examples of distributing nltk using 
    Hadoop -file
but nothing for Pig.

TIA!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem is because I'm using Jython:

```
`REGISTER 'PigParse.py' using jython as PP;
```

and [you can't use lxml with Jython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117349/can-i-call-external-python-functions-from-google-refine/9117673#9117673)